# KSH - Check if date is in BST/GMT and perform calculations

Tags: date, unix, time, ksh

I have a small KSH that performs what seems to be, on the surface, a relatively simple function. A date gets passed in (in the format YYYYMMDD), and this checks whether it falls within BST. If it is within BST, 5 hours is added to it and assigned to "BST_START_DATE", and 29 hours is added to assign to "BST_END_DATE". If not, 6/30 hours are added.

So for example, if the date was 20150330, you would get the following:

```
BST_START_DATE:2015033005
BST_END_DATE:2015033105
```

This generally works fine, except when for days where the timezone changes. Using the date 20150328, I would expect START to be given 06 (as it's outside BST) but end to be given 05 (as it's within). Instead, 20150328 and 20150329 both return 06 for both values, and it's not until 20150330 that it begins working correctly. I've been scratching my head for a while trying to figure it out, but I'm relatively unfamiliar with the intricacies of the date function.

Code below:

```
P_CB_DATA_DATE=$1

DATE1=${P_CB_DATA_DATE}
DATE2=`date -d "${P_CB_DATA_DATE} +1 day" "+%Y%m%d"`

BST_START=`date +%Y`03`cal 3 \`date +%Y\` | sed -n 's/^\([0-9]\{2\}\).*/\1/p' | tail -1`
BST_END=`date +%Y`10`cal 10 \`date +%Y\` | sed -n 's/^\([0-9]\{2\}\).*/\1/p' | tail -1`

if [[ ${DATE1} -ge ${BST_START} && ${DATE1} -le ${BST_END} ]]
then
export BCD_START_DATE=`date -d "${DATE1} +5 hours" "+%Y%m%d%H"`
echo "START is in BST"
else
export BCD_START_DATE=`date -d "${DATE1} +6 hours" "+%Y%m%d%H"`
echo "START is not in BST"
fi

if [[ ${DATE2} -ge ${BST_START} && ${DATE2} -le ${BST_END} ]]
then
export BCD_END_DATE=`date -d "${DATE1} +29 hours" "+%Y%m%d%H"`
echo "END is in BST"
else
export BCD_END_DATE=`date -d "${DATE1} +30 hours" "+%Y%m%d%H"`
echo "END is not in BST"
fi
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

> A date gets passed in (in the format YYYYMMDD), and this checks
>   whether it falls within BST. If it is within BST, 5 hours is added to it and assigned to "BST_START_DATE", and 29 hours is added to assign to "BST_END_DATE". If not, 6/30 hours are added.

Here you say that the passed-in date (*it*) is being checked.

> Using the date 20150328, I would expect START to be given 06 (as it's
>   outside BST) but end to be given 05 (as it's within).

Contrary to the first statement, herefrom (as well as from your script) can be seen that *START* and *END* are being checked separately. You should word the question more carefully.

> Instead, 20150328 and 20150329 both return 06 for both values

You seem to have missed that 20150328 (0 h) plus 29 hours yields 20150329, 6 o'clock indeed. So, your script does what you say you want it to do. Whether that is what you really want is another story.